# Java: Else without an if

Tags: java, condiciones, else

Estoy siguiedo un video sobre un programa y estoy haciendo los mismos pasos, pero me sale el error **Else without an if** en todos los else if.

Hasta ahora consulté en internet, pero no hallé mucha informacion sobre como resolverlo. [Este es el video](https://youtu.be/e1Ktv9AlwjU?si=tNyehRkU0zhmJmgn) por si a caso.

```
double[] R = new double[14];

R[0] = Double.parseDouble(txtmat.getText());
R[1] = Double.parseDouble(txting.getText());
R[2] = Double.parseDouble(txtbio.getText());
R[3] = Double.parseDouble(txtprogram.getText());
R[4] = Double.parseDouble(txtquim.getText());
R[5] = Double.parseDouble(txtfisi.getText());
R[6] = Double.parseDouble(txtdis.getText());
R[7] = Double.parseDouble(txtempren.getText());

R[8] = (R[0] + R[1] +  R[2] + R[3] +   R[4] + R[5] + R[6] + R[7]) / 8;
R[9] = R[0] + R[1] +  R[2] + R[3] +   R[4] + R[5] + R[6] + R[7];

String Promedio = String.format("%.Of", R[8]);
txtprom.setText(Promedio);

String PuntajeTotal = String.format("%.Of", R[9]);
txttpunt.setText(PuntajeTotal);

if (R[9]) >= 700)
{
    txtclasi.setText("1st");
}
else if (R[9]) <= 600)
{
    txtclasi.setText("2do");
}
 else if (R[9]) >= 500)
{
    txtclasi.setText("3er");
}
else if (R[9]) >= 400)
{
    txtclasi.setText("3");
}
else if (R[9]) >= 300)
{
    txtclasi.setText("CoHE");
}
else if (R[9]) >= 200)
{
    txtclasi.setText("Fail");
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Leila, bienvenida al sitio. No están bien balanceados los paréntesis en las condiciones, te sobra un ). Debería ser: (R[9] >= 700). Y así en todos.

Comment: @RubioRic correcto, quiza puedas ponerlo como respuesta

Comment: @JonathanG Es un error tipográfico. Hay un apartado específico para cerrar este tipo de preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Te sobran paréntesis en todos los condicionales.

```
if (R[9] >= 700)
{
    txtclasi.setText("1st");
}
else if (R[9] <= 600)
{
    txtclasi.setText("2do");
}
 else if (R[9] >= 500)
{
    txtclasi.setText("3er");
}
else if (R[9] >= 400)
{
    txtclasi.setText("3");
}
else if (R[9] >= 300)
{
    txtclasi.setText("CoHE");
}
else if (R[9] >= 200)
{
    txtclasi.setText("Fail");
}
```

Estas cosas las puedes detectar muy fácilmente utilizando cualquier IDE moderno, ya que te marca este tipo de errores e incluso algunos te dan automáticamente la solución.